# RLC circuit (simulation in Scilab)

Tags: circuit-analysis, simulation

I tried to solve a RLC circuit and I obtained the matrix. I tried to do a circuit in Scilab, but I didn't obtain a sinusoidal response. The output is in the capacitor and the input is the step function. Why didn't I get the sinusoidal response?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1) You should run the simulation for a longer time, but you will likely still see no sinusoidal response. 2) Why do you expect a sinusoidal response? (Could you please motivate?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circuit is overdamped. The output will rise to v(t)/5 with no overshoot. If you rerun the simulation with smaller values of resistors, you'll see the damped sinusoids you were expecting.

Comment: Hello … anybody out there? I'm surprised I provided the only answer. Normally someone - lots of someones - would provide definitions of overdamped and critically damped, and calculations for component values for the cases. The answer was obvious.